# Including filtering-criteria in Tweepy Streaming API

Tags: python, twitter, streaming, tweepy

I would like to collect all tweets that contain on the following words:
*Bitcoin, Ethereum, Litecoin or Denarius*

However, I want to exclude tweets than can be classified as retweets and tweets that contain links. I know from the following website (https://www.followthehashtag.com/help/hidden-twitter-search-operators-extra-power-followthehashtag) that I can add *-filter:links* to exclude tweets that contain links. This is clearly visible by comparing the following search term;

https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&vertical=news&q=Bitcoin&src=typd

[image]

with https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&q=Bitcoin%20-filter%3Alinks&src=typd

[image]

The same applies for retweets, where I can use *-filter:retweets* (see https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&q=Bitcoin%20-filter%3Aretweets&src=typd)

I want to add these criteria to make sure that I reduce the "noise" and be less likely to violate any API-limitations. 
I wrote the following Python-script:

```
import sys
import time
import json
import pandas as pd
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

USER_KEY = ''
USER_SECRET = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN = ''
ACCESS_SECRET = ''

crypto_tickers = ['bitcoin', 'ethereum', 'litecoin', 'denarius', '-filter:links', '-filter:retweets']

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

def on_data(self, data):
    tweet = json.loads(data)
    print(tweet)


def on_error(self, status):
    if status == 420:
        sys.stderr.write('Enhance Your Calm; The App Is Being Rate Limited For Making Too Many Requests')
        return True
    else:
        sys.stderr.write('Error {}n'.format(status))
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
listener =  StdOutListener()
auth = OAuthHandler(USER_KEY, USER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET)

stream = Stream(auth, listener)
stream.filter(languages=['en'], track=crypto_tickers)
```

However, the output clearly shows tweets that are retweets and contain links. [image]

Q1: How can I correctly include the search criteria  in my script and get the correct output?

Q2: According to the official documentation the Streaming API allows up to 400 track keywords (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/overview/statuses-filter.html). Do my two filter criteria classify as 2 track keywords?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A1. You cannot use the `-filter:` syntax on the Streaming API. The full list of available options is [here in the documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/basic-stream-parameters). The syntax you are trying to use is specific to the REST search API, not the standard realtime filter API (note that, in the enterprise realtime PowerTrack API, you *can* achieve what you are asking about, but this a commercial API).

A2. You have 6 track keywords in your code, including the `-filter:` elements, but those will never match.